# List the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think the answer is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n$ is all the factors of $26$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$26 = 2\cdot 13$. Both 2 and 13 are the prime factors of $26$, and cannot be reduced further.
So we know that So $$\mathbb Z_{26} \equiv \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{13}$$

We have Lagrange Theorem to thank for proving that:

"...for any finite group $G,$ the order (number of elements) of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G.$ The converse of the theorem applies **only** to cyclic groups.

More to the point: You need to prove that these are, and are the only, subgroups of $\mathbb Z_{26}$:

$\mathbb Z_{26},\; \{0\},\; \{0,13\},$ and $\{0, 2,4,6,8,10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24\}.$

Notice the orders of of the groups listed: in order, we have $26, 1, 2, 13 $, which all divide $26$ (with no remainder).

And, indeed, we have that a cyclic group of order $n$ is ***isomorphic*** to the group $\mathbb Z_n$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite: Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $n|26$, but such a $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ in a strict sense. The list of subgroups is the following:

- trivial subgroups: $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$, $\{0\}$
- non-trivial subgroups: $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24\}$, $\{0,13\}$.

Can you prove by yourself that these are indeed *all* subgroups? Do you see why the first non-trivial subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ and the second one is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$?